# Databricks pyspark - BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler log to Azure Blob container in single file

Tags: logging, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am using BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler to write logs from databricks to an Azure blob container. My code has 3 log statements and I want all 3 to be written to a single file, but each statement is being written to a separate file in the blob container. How do I get all log statements in one file?

```
import logging
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

log = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = "name.csv",account_name="xyz",account_key="&&&",maxBytes=5000,container="abc")
azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)
log.info("Start processing file....")
log.info("Processsed file successfully")
log.info("End file successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler), `RotatingFileHandler` does not upload the log until the log content does not reach the maxBytes and proceeds to upload multiple files consequently when it exceeds the maxBytes.

> When this file is filled, it is closed and renamed to app.log.1, and if files app.log.1, app.log.2, etc.

Another reason you are facing this issue is because the filename of the blob is somehow getting appended with the timestamp (i.e., the time at which the log is getting uploaded).

One of the workarounds that you can try is instead of using `BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler` you can try using `TableStorageHandler` where the results are displayed in the below format.

> | PartitionKey | RowKey | Timestamp | message |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | XXXXX | XXXXXXXXX | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |
> | XXXXX | XXXXXXXXX | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |
> | XXXXX | XXXXXXXXX | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |

**REFERENCES:** [azure-storage-logging](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-logging/#:%7E:text=The%20BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler%20class%20is%20a%20subclass%20of%20logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler,when%20the%20current%20file%20reaches%20a%20certain%20size.)